# How to change the list of dictionaries to defined data frame format?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a list of dictionaries which is as follows,

```
list_of_dict = [{"mac":"0010403bf0db", "rssi":-42, 
                 "gw_mac":"b827eb36fb0b", "detail":"main_building"}, 
                {"mac":"0010403bf0db", "rssi":-87, 
                 "gw_mac":"d827fc36gc0c", "detail":"main_building"}]
```

How do I convert the above list of dictionaries to below mentioned data frame format?

```
required_df = mac            detail        b827eb36fb0b      d827fc36gc0c
              0010403bf0db   main_building  -42              -87
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create `DataFrame` by contructor and if values in `mac`, `detail` and `gw_mac` are unique is possible reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df  = (pd.DataFrame(list_of_dict)
         .set_index(['mac','detail', 'gw_mac'])['rssi']
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
            mac         detail  b827eb36fb0b  d827fc36gc0c
0  0010403bf0db  main_building           -42           -87
```

If not unique values in 3 columns, is necessary aggregation by [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df  = (pd.DataFrame(list_of_dict)
         .pivot_table(index=['mac','detail'],columns='gw_mac',values='rssi', aggfunc='mean')
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
            mac         detail  b827eb36fb0b  d827fc36gc0c
0  0010403bf0db  main_building           -42           -87
```